# Uploading videos to facebook with the ActionScript Graph Api

Tags: video, upload, facebook-as3-api

I'm searching for hours now and cant find anything related to the subject anywhere!

Basically what I have right now:

1)Adobe air 2 app that records the webcam input for 10 seconds and saves it as an .flv video on the local machine.

2)when the video is saved a facebook login window pops up and upon "connection success"
(session!=null)
the upload proccess shuld begin.

I once made an application that easyli upload photos:

var params:Object = {image:bitMapData, title:'test Title', fileName:'test Img'};

FacebookDesktop.api('me/photos', onShareComplete, params);

So I hoped for a solution if a form of:

var params:Object = {source:'/vidFolder/vid.flv, title:'testTitle', fileName:'testVideo'};

FacebookDesktop.api('me/videos', onShareComplete, params);

wuld work but I guess that passing a source to a local file is what makes it triky.

Anyway... I'd be greatfull if anyone can give me an example of how can this be achived without using PHP, or any example of AS3/PHP/JS  hybrid that can achive this goal.

I have a full control of the PC that the applications is running on, basically it will be a touchscreen kiosk that users will record them self and then upload the video to their facebook. so I can run PHP on the local machin of something like that, I just need a direction 'cuz im runnin on ice at the moment.

tnx in advance

EDIT:

there is a parameter in one of the the API's classes:

/** * URL for uploading videos via Graph API. * */ 
public static var VIDEO_URL:String = 'graph-video.facebook.com';

but as I said, there is no documentation, ANYWHARE, oh how when or why to use it.

(p.s sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

upload video want a different server than photos
video -> https://graph-video.facebook.com/ 
photo -> https://graph.facebook.com/

i suppose FacebookDesktop.api use https://graph.facebook.com/ by default, so you should check if it can be set as required